# Symfony Doctrine with FosElastic how to search from ORM and Elastic together?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, doctrine-orm, foselasticabundle

For example

my entity has fields:

id (int)

title (text) (stored also in elastic)

content (text) (stored also in elastic)

categoryId (int)

status (int)

and i want to search text from title,content i use

```
//RepositoryManagerInterface $finder
$results = $finder->getRepository(Offer::class)->find('AUDI A6 C6 2.0');
```

when i want search in database example by categoryId

```
$offers = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Offer::class)->customOfferQueryBuilderWithResult(['categoryId'=>5]);
```

how to search it together?
do I have to store categoryId also in elastic?

Comment: if i cant do this, pleas tell me, and i create better index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Repository method

/**
 * @param int $id
 * @return Query
 */
public function getByOfferId(int $id): Query
{
    $terms = new Terms('categoryId', [$id]);
    $boolQuery = (new BoolQuery())->addMust($terms);
    return (new Query())->setQuery($boolQuery);
}
```